# Breakpoint in netbeans 8.1 with javaScript application not working properly

Tags: google-chrome, netbeans, netbeans-platform, netbeans-plugins, netbeans-8.1

I'm using netbeans 8.1 for developing a javaScript web application and its works fine now. But I'd like to enable a breakpoint in my jquery code and install netbeans connector to chrome. But while the project start to rum it shows **"Unresolved breakpoint: not resolved/inactive at current line."**[image]

[image: Bellow shows the screen while run the application]

Please feel free to respond your thoughts regarding the same

thanks
Jyothis